# Symfony, Doctrine and Oracle Date field

Tags: oracle, symfony, doctrine

I have a Symfony 6 project with a Doctrine Entity that is tied to an Oracle database and I've listed the column definition and setter/getters below. The Oracle column type is Date and is formatted as 08-JUN-20 if I view it in Oracle Developer.

```
#[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE, nullable: true)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $next_expected_date = null;


public function getNextExpectedDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
{
    return $this->next_expected_date;
}

public function setNextExpectedDate(?\DateTimeInterface $next_expected_date): static
{
    $this->next_expected_date = $next_expected_date;

    return $this;
}
```

I am trying to test an update to the table that keeps failing. I've tried creating DateTime and DateTimeInterface and DateTimeImmutable objects to pass to setNextExpectedData() but I keep getting this error: "An exception occurred while executing a query: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string".

Here are a few of the ways I've tried to create a date object to pass to no avail:

```
$next_expected_date = \DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', "2021-01-04");

$date = new \DateTime("2021-01-04 23:59:59");
$next_expected_date = \DateTimeImmutable::createFromInterface($date);
```

My next step will be to try to just write out the query in Doctrine to do my update but I wanted to try and get this working first if possible. Any help or pointers are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Something appears to be getting lost in translation between your code and the implemented SQL. Can't say much more without knowing what the generated SQL looks like, and how the format string in its `to_date` function call differs from the string literal of your data. Note that the `date` data type in Oracle is binary and doesn't have a "format". Format is only applied at the time data is selected, based on an implicit system default or an explicit conversion using `to_char` with a format mask. A similar format mask should be used with `to_date` to convert a string literal to a `date`.

Comment: Thanks @pmdba. Unfortunately I can't see the generated SQL because Symfony/Doctrine errors out before it finishes creating the query. I'm in the process of trying to write the query out with Doctirne's query builder so I can use to_date to see if that helps. If that doesn't work I'll write out the raw query and do it that way.